# How to output textfile content using npp_exec

Tags: nppexec

Npp_Exec does not recognize Type command to list file content, any Idea how to print content of a textfile with Npp_exec?

I need the equivalent to `type filename` in npp_exec.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `cmd` comandline to run a command like `type` or `dir` inside the console. An example NppExec script looks like this:

```
cmd /c type $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
```